# Highcharts date time axis

Tags: datetime, highcharts, timeline

I want a stacked bar chart with time displayed on y axis as in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fu5ord0/).

Times on y axis is coming as 00:00 for all the values. I would like to know why it is not showing different times. For two bars the width of different section should be different because they have different time but it is coming as equal for every data. Data passed by me is UTC milliseconds. Both the bars start at same level even though they have different starting values.

I am trying to achieve is something like this:
[image: Screenshot Example]

Here's my code:

```js
var chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [ 'Actual', 'Scheduled' ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        type : 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats : {
         day: '%H:%M'
        },
        labels:{formatter :function(){
            console.log(this.value);
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
        }},
        opposite: true,
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 1428042300000,
            label :{text :'current time'} 
        }]
    },
    tooltip : {
        formatter : function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.y) + ': <b>' + this.series.name;
        }
      },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels :{enabled:true,formatter :function(){ if(this.y){return this.series.name}}}
        }
    },
    series: [{"name":"Take-Off","data":[null,1428042300000]},{"name":"Off-Block","data":[null,1428042300000]},{"name":"In-Block","data":[null,1428038700000]},{"name":"Landing","data":[1428038160000,1428038700000]}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bars appear identical widths because they're representing the relative values of the dates you're passing in, i.e. the whole number of milliseconds since epoch. You need to work out the time span for each stage and plot those instead.

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/3fu5ord0/1/

P.S. Apparently I can't post a jsfiddle link without some code:

```
series: [{"name": "Take-Off","data": 3600000}] // etc.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, resultant graph seems exactly what I need , but I still dont understand what was the issue with my data, in your data it seems you have kept day as 1st jan 1970 and you are just changing the time.And why is it needed to add a certain milliseconds in label formatter.Even though landing time is 00:13 , in graph it is near to 06:25

Comment: The bars are representing the lengths of given numbers but you're passing in the entire time which has passed between your start times and 1970, which are proportionally not very different from each other, hence similar bar lengths. You need to pass in the length of time each bar represents, not each start time.